# is '--remote-debugger-port' supposed to work with casper 1.1.2 and phantomjs 2.1.1?

Tags: javascript, debugging, phantomjs, casperjs, remote-debugging

I try this very simple script :

```
debugger;
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote: ' + msg);
})

casper.start('http://stackoverflow.com');

casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
    var ps = document.querySelectorAll('*');
    console.log("DEBUG ps.length="+ps.length);

})

casper.run(function() {
     this.exit();
});
```

then I run

```
casperjs --remote-debugger-port=9035 script.js
```

Then I open http://127.0.0.1:9035 in chrome, click on the `bootstrap.js` link, then open `console` tab, type `__run()`, but all get hangs.

**Is this feature supposed to work properly ?**

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck on this several hours, and didn't fix this completely.

Still I can give you some hints.

1. Using another browser，In my case, using Safari instead of Chrome.
   https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12864
2. Using phantomjs to check the code if work well.

   // casperscript.js
   phantom.casperPath = '/path/to/casperjs';
   phantom.injectJs(phantom.casperPath + '/bin/bootstrap.js');

   var casper = require('casper').create();
   // ...
3. After step1/step2, maybe you still get other issues(such like crash)..So you'd better add resource listener  or capture screenshots to see what really happened.